React-Native: How can I load Pdf with Document Picker and then show the document in the view without getting error Permission Denial?
I've been trying to Show PDF with react-native-pdf, I keep getting problem with access to content:// because the access is denied by Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider ...
This is how I pick the document:
function pickFile() {
    DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
        type: \[DocumentPicker.types.allFiles\],
    })
    .then((response) =\> {
        console.log(response);
        setPickedFile(response);
    })
    .catch((error) =\> {
        console.error(error);
    });
}

I'm expecting can use that response to show the pdf with view.
But I have no idea what can I do.
